# How to remove a value from a dynamically generated Json Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```js
{
        "1": {
            "0": [
                7606,
                7615,
                7596,
                7513,
                7514,
                7597,
                7605,
                7607,
                7608,
                7595
            ],
            "87": [
                7514,
                7605,
                7644,
                7607,
                7608
            ]
        },
         "2": {
            "0": [
                7573,
                7605,
                7572,
                7569
            ]
         },
         "3": { ....

}
```

I have this Following demo Json array . Note - There can be other objects too inside `1` or `2`...

I need to remove the value of the array element which contains any value which matched in a  given array `[7605,7608,7615,7573]`. I need to remove all these values form the above json array .

How can i recursively traverse the following array and remove all these values from the leaf array of the object  .

For the above input the output should be

```
{
        "1": {
            "0": [
                7606,
                7596,
                7513,
                7514,
                7597,
                7607,
                7595
            ],
            "87": [
                7514,
                7644,
                7607
            ]
        },
         "2": {
            "0": [
                7568,
                7572,
                7569
            ]
         }
}
```

I tried using Object.keys but i am confused with the dynamic nature of the json.

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: Where specifically are you stuck? What has your research turned up? A thorough [search](/help/searching) here on SO should turn up the things you need to do this.

Comment: Just to make things clearer, can any number inside your object be an array of other numbers? I mean, for example, can the value 7568 that is in `obj['2']['0']` be an array of other numbers? that is `obj['2']['0']['7568']` be an array of numbers. is your structure dynamic or static

Comment: Show us the code of what you have tried.

Comment: 7568 is static but the json key and values can be dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter` method which accepts a **callback** function in combination with `Object.keys` method.

The `forEach()` method executes a provided function once for each array element.

The `indexOf()` is used in order to returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

The `filter` method creates a **new** array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the **provided** function.

`forEach` is used in order to iterating the object keys, then use `filter` method in order to remove items from **array**(those items which also exists in the given array `[7605,7608,7615,7573]`).

Also you can use `includes` method in order to check the presence of item in a given array.

```
json[key][subkey]=json[key][subkey].filter(function(item){
  return !array.includes(item);
});
```

```js
let array=[7605,7608,7615,7573];
let json={
        "1": {
            "0": [
                7606,
                7615,
                7596,
                7513,
                7514,
                7597,
                7605,
                7607,
                7608,
                7595
            ],
            "87": [
                7514,
                7605,
                7644,
                7607,
                7608
            ]
        },
         "2": {
            "0": [
                7573,
                7605,
                7572,
                7569
            ]
         }
}
Object.keys(json).forEach(function(key){
  Object.keys(json[key]).forEach(function(subkey){
    json[key][subkey]=json[key][subkey].filter(function(item){
      return array.indexOf(item)==-1;
    });
  });
});
console.log(json);
```

Comment: thanks @Alex . I dont want to blindly copy and paste a small explanation will be great . thanks a lot. this line `  json[key][subkey]=json[key][subkey].filter(function(item){ ` is line going over the head

Comment: `filter` method only creates a new array..so you need to update the key's array with the array filtered.

Comment: filter method does not mutate the original array, only creates a new one and you have to assign new value.

Comment: If you want to mutate the original array use `splice` method.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in noting that `Object.keys()` is helpful in implementing a solution for a dynamic object such as this, but here's a possible recursive implementation employing the use of `Object.entries()` instead:

```js
function filterObject(o, v) {
  return Object
    .entries(o).map(([key, value]) => {
      if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        value = value.filter(n => !v.includes(n))
      } else {
        value = filterObject(value, v)
      }

      return [key, value]
    })
    .reduce((o, [key, value]) => {
      return Object.assign(o, {
        [key]: value
      })
    }, {})
}

console.log(filterObject({
  "1": {
    "0": [
      7606,
      7615,
      7596,
      7513,
      7514,
      7597,
      7605,
      7607,
      7608,
      7595
    ],
    "87": [
      7514,
      7605,
      7644,
      7607,
      7608
    ]
  },
  "2": {
    "0": [
      7573,
      7605,
      7572,
      7569
    ]
  }
}, [7605, 7608, 7615, 7573]))
```

MDN's polyfills for various functions:

- [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill)
- [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries#Polyfill)
- [`Array#includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Polyfill)

Comment: @INFOSYS No problem. If you'd like clarifications of anything, just leave a comment here with any specific questions you have and I'll update my answer to address them.

Comment: the only issue i have is i am using `node 0.10.24` for production and guess both object.keys and assign might not work i need to use underscore for that i guess

Comment: @INFOSYS for backwards compatibility, you can use babel to compile any JavaScript versions or even some non-standard language extensions like React's JSX, into compliant ES5 equivalent code, which is capable of running on even IE8 in many cases. However, `Object.keys()` _should_ already exist in node v0.10, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @INFOSYS I've also added MDN links to suggested polyfills for those functions, should you be interested.